# System Files Edit Without Root?

Tags: root-access

can I change system files on my android without them being rooted. And does changing the files mean my phone is now rooted ?

Comment: 1) No, you don't have permission to access it. 2) No, changing them is not the same as rooting at all.

Comment: @AndrewT. I guess that depends on how you interpret the question. :) Yeah, changing system files is not *the same* as rooting, but as Izzy pointed out, modifying system files (directly) does mean the phone *is* rooted, because if it weren't, you wouldn't be able to monkey around with system files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most system files are protected in different ways.

### "system files" viewed as "managed by the Android system"

- everybody can read them, but only root<sup>1</sup> can modify ("read-only" for all non-root)
- only root<sup>1</sup> has access to them at all ("invisible" for all non-root)

So no: without rooting the device, you cannot modify them *directly*. Nevertheless, some of them can be modified *indirectly*, using the appropriate "activities" implemented in the Android GUI – which you might know as "Settings screens".

### "system files" viewed as "located on the `/system` partition"

Here the entire [file-system](/questions/tagged/file-system) is mounted read-only – and only root can make it writeable.

---

The second part of your question is answered implicitly: root being a requirement to edit those files would implicate your device is rooted when you're able to modify them. But before drawing wrong conclusions, you should be sure the file you've modified really is a "system file". To find out whether your device is rooted, there are better means: "[root checker](http://www.appbrain.com/search?q=root%20checker)".

---

<sup>**1:** sometimes there are dedicated system processes with elevated privileges, able to "trigger a modification" – this is how those GUI elements (in *Settings*) work.</sup>

Comment: Always glad to help, @Ekene! When it solved your problem, please mark the answer "accepted" (by clicking the check-mark next to it) – so it gets visible as "solved" in search results etc.